# Should I connect child component to avoid re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm developing an application using Next.js, react-redux.

Below code is part of my application.

1. Click 'Save button'
2. Dispatch action 'toggleBookmarked'
3. Update Button's text in ListItem

```js
    // items

    [
      {id: 1, title: 'title1', is_bookmarked: true},
      {id: 2, title: 'title2', is_bookmarked: false}
    ]


    // components/molecules/ListItem.js

    const ListItem = React.memo(({ item, handleClick }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{item.title}</p>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>
            {item.is_bookmarked ? 'Unsave' : 'Save'}
          </button>
        </div>
      )
    })

    export default ListItem



    // components/organisms/Results.js

    const Results = ({ items, toggleBookmark }} => {
      return items.map(item => (
        <ListItem
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          handleClick={() => toggleBookmark(item.id)}
        />
      ))
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      items: state.classified.items,
    })

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        toggleBookmark: bindActionCreators(toggleBookmark, dispatch)
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Results)



    // action.js

    export const toggleBookmark = (id) => async dispatch => {
      return dispatch({ type: classifiedActionTypes.TOGGLE_BOOKMARK, payload: id })
    }



    // reducer.js

    export default function reducer(state = [], action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.TOGGLE_BOOKMARK:
          return {
            ...state,
            items: state.items.map(el => el.id === action.payload ? { ...el, is_bookmarked: !el.is_bookmarked } : el)
          }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

When I turn on Highlight update(react devtools) and click save button, all ListItem.js re-renders. I want only component which is clicked to re-render.

I tried using { connect } inside ListItem then dispatch there, it worked. Only ListItem which is clicked re-rendered.
But I want only parent component(Results.js) to connect to store. How can only clicked child component re-render without connecting to store inside child component?

Sorry for my poor English

**ADDITIONAL IMAGE**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `ListItem` will re-render every time because `handleClick` changes every time. You are creating a new function for each one every time `Search` re-renders, so your current use of `React.memo` has no real effect. In this case, it should be pretty easy to work around. Instead of passing the new function every time, just pass `toggleBookmark` down:

```js
    const Search = ({ items, toggleBookmark }} => {
      return items.map(item => (
        <ListItem
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          handleClick={toggleBookmark}
        />
      ))
    }
```

Then modify your `ListItem` to pass it's own ID to it:

```js
    const ListItem = React.memo(({ item, handleClick }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{item.title}</p>
          <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>
            {item.is_bookmarked ? 'Unsave' : 'Save'}
          </button>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

Because you are memoizing the `ListItem`, it will only re-render if `item` or `handleClick` change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified code as you said. But all ListItem still re-render when I click save button. I mean, Blue border appears to all ListItem through Highlight update function.

Comment: I put console.log('re-render') to ListItem. Only clicked ListItem shows 're-render' in console, so it worked as you said. Thank you so much. But I don't know why Highlight update function shows blue border to all ListItems when I clicked save button.

Comment: Glad to hear it was actually working, you had me pretty stumped trying to figure out what was happening =). Is this highlight you are referring to the browser showing you what updated, or is this a styling thing you have somewhere else that may not be behaving as expected?

Comment: Yes, it is. I checked 'Highlight updates when components render.' in Chrome's 'Components' tab. This function shows which components updated (re-rendered), right? I expect only clicked ListItem will highlight, but all ListItem will highlight. I don't know why. Is it meaning all ListItems still re-render?

Comment: I honestly haven't used it much...that said, keep in mind that the `Search` element itself is re-rendering, and presumably all of the `ListItem` components are contained within its bounds. So a blue rectangle around all of them may be expected. If individual components were updating, would you expect many individual boxes, or does it just put a border around the top-most element that re-renders?

Comment: I understood what you are saying. But I can't answer properly because of my English. Sorry about that. So I added image which all ListItems highlighted when clicked button. But console shows only one 're-render'.